# How to reduce the size of the vertices in `tkz-graph`?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tkz-graph

How to reduce the size of the Vertex in the following `tkz-graph`??

[image]

### MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
%
\Vertex[L=\hbox{$P_1$},x=2cm,y=0cm]{v0}
\Vertex[L=\hbox{$P_2$},style={left=.5cm},x=0cm,y=0.0cm]{v1}
\Vertex[L=\hbox{$P_3$},style={left=.5cm},x=0.0cm,y=2.5cm]{v2}
\Vertex[L=\hbox{$P_4$},x=2.0cm,y=2.5cm]{v3}
%

\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={post}}
\Edge[](v0)(v1)
\Edge[](v1)(v2)
\Edge[](v2)(v3)
\Edge[](v3)(v0)
\Edge[](v3)(v1)
%
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you want to create a new style, you can play with `minimum size` and `inner sep` inside a `append style` key to modify predefined `VertexStyle` style.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
%
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.append style={minimum size=1pt, inner sep=1pt}}

\Vertex[L=\hbox{$P_1$},x=2cm,y=0cm]{v0}
\Vertex[L=\hbox{$P_2$},style={left=.5cm},x=0cm,y=0.0cm]{v1}
\Vertex[L=\hbox{$P_3$},style={left=.5cm},x=0.0cm,y=2.5cm]{v2}
\Vertex[L=\hbox{$P_4$},x=2.0cm,y=2.5cm]{v3}
%

\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={post}}
\Edge[](v0)(v1)
\Edge[](v1)(v2)
\Edge[](v2)(v3)
\Edge[](v3)(v0)
\Edge[](v3)(v1)
%
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried with `style ={inner sep = 1pt}` in each vertex like `\Vertex[L=\hbox{$\{1\}$},style ={inner sep = 1pt}]{v0}`. I didnt get effect. But it didnt work whereas works well with ./append style..why??

Comment: And if possible, how do i define this setup for the complete document where i have more than 30 graphs like this.. So that it will be easy for me style the vertices globally.

Comment: @David If you move `GraphStyle` and `.append style` to document preamble, they will be applied to all `tikzpictures` in your document.

Comment: @David `graph-tkz` is based on `TikZ` but it's a different package with different rules. It's documentation is written in french but it's full of examples and not too difficult to understand.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have read the documentation and there was no information about define globally in preamble.

Comment: And I am not sure how to change the arrow style also. Documentation does not explain that too.

Comment: @David Chapter 7 explain how to change nodes and chapter 8 how to change links. But you also need to know something about `TikZ` to understand how `.style` works.